# Review site specifically for Apple products?

Tags: app-store-connect, websites

I am wondering if there is a product review site specifically for apple products?

Comment: Solely for Apple products?

Comment: Yep, just for apple products :) Apart from the apple site of course, because I'm sure apple they screen those reviews.

Comment: I've actually read lots of very critical reviews (of Apple products) at Apple online store too, so I wouldn't dis it too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean reviews of Apple-produced (and only Apple-produced) hardware and software? Or reviews of software and accessories by anyone for Macs, iPods, iPhones, iPads, etc.?

If the latter, there's always [Macworld's review section](http://www.macworld.com/reviews.html).

If the former, you could combine the RSS feeds for Macworld's [Mac reviews](http://www.macworld.com/products/mac.html) + [iPod review](http://www.macworld.com/products/ipod.html) + [iPhone reviews](http://www.macworld.com/reviews/products/browse/results.do?catId=2119&mid=48) + [iPad reviews](http://www.macworld.com/products/tablets.html), I guess.

Comment: Yep, just apple products like the iMac, iPhone, OS X, etc ...

Comment: Couldn't find it quickly looking at their site, but MacUser in their print magazine have an Apple hardware roundup at the back of each issue with tweaked review ratings based on how the product compares here and now, rather than when it was initially reviewed.

Comment: @Nippysaurus - well, then, your answer's above. Macworld generally does solid reviews of whatever Apple's shipping.

Comment: @Chops - You're referring to [www.macuser.co.uk](http://www.macuser.co.uk), I presume? Here in the US, it's been a *long* time since I last saw MacUser in print.

Answer (score 1):

For Apple's mobile products, http://www.ilounge.com/ is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

As far as software goes, [MacUpdate](http://macupdate.com) is pretty good.  They have lots of user reviews, and the ability for users to suggest similar software is awesome.  I've found many a free alternative to a poorly reviewed commercial app that way.

As a side note, [alternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net) is another great way to find alternates.

Answer (score 1):

There's always ArsTechnica. Yes, they do review other stuff besides just Apple stuff, but I fail to see how that should disqualify them, especially given the quality and depth of the reviews. And with a couple of clicks, you can specify Apple reviews:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/